# Detect if anchor elements contain only lowercase text?

Tags: jquery

I need to append a class that does `text-transform: capitalize` to a large keyword list, but I need to ignore any keywords that already have capitalized letters in it like `eXample`.

I know how to complete the task, apart from where I'd only add the class to non-capitalized keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all your `a` elements, and then filter them on ones with aren't already entirely lowercase...

```
$("a")
  .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == $(this).text().toLowerCase(); })
  .addClass("uppercase-me");
```

For the hell of it, if jQuery wasn't around...

```
[].forEach.call(document.links, function(a) {
    var text = a.textContent;
    if (text == text.toLowerCase()) {
        a.classList.add("uppercase-me");
    }
});
```

If you're using IE -4...

```
var a = document.links;
var aLength = a.length;
var text;

while (--aLength) {
     text = a.textContent || a.innerText;
     if (text == text.toLowerCase()) {
         a.className += "uppercase-me";
     }
}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Didn't think of comparing the string to a a lowercase processed version of it. Thanks :)

Actually -- the first version you have on top still appends the class uppercase-me to anchors that have uppercased letters in them.

Comment: Why doesn't it work here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mbb5D/3/

Comment: @red I suck and I got my condition wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I love how you included an IE-4 example :D